# Получение данных json через ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Есть json файл:

```
{
    "list":
    [
       {"country": "USA", "region": "North America", "population": 321368000000},
       {"country": "Russia", "region": "Europe/Asia", "population": 146880432},
    ]
}
```

Есть такой код:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", 'list.json', true);

xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState ===4) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('country')[0].innerHTML =
xhr.responseText
};

if(xhr.status !=200) {
    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
};
```

}

Как мне передать в html отдельные значение json? Я знаю что нужно использовать json.parse, но не пойму к чему его применить.

Comment: Для наглядности сразу что будет где - `json.parse(xhr.responseText).list[0].country == USA`, `json.parse(xhr.responseText).list[1].country == Russia`

Comment: Что-то у вас в США население больше, чем было людей за всё существование человечества ;)